# 'self' captured by a closure before all members were initialized swift 3

Tags: swift, asynchronous, initialization

Here's my current code:

```
import UIKit

class Pet: NSObject, NSCoding {

// Mark: - Member Variables
public var id: Int?
public var name: String?
public var groupID: Int?
public var breedID: Int?
public var weight: Int?
public var chipNum: Int?
public var imageURL: String?
public var petImage: UIImage?
public var dispatch = DispatchGroup()

init(id: Int, name: String, groupID: Int, breedID: Int, weight: Int, chipNum: Int, imageURL: String) {
    self.id = id
    self.name = name
    self.groupID = groupID
    self.breedID = breedID
    self.weight = weight
    self.chipNum = chipNum
    self.imageURL = imageURL
    self.petImage = UIImage()

    dispatch.enter()
    //line below is causing: 'self' captured by a closure before all members were initialized
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async {
        // This needs to be async
        if self.imageURL != "" {
            let url: URL = URL(string: self.imageURL!)!
            let imageData: Data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
            self.petImage = UIImage(data: imageData)
        }
    }
    dispatch.wait()
}

// MARK: - Persist User Data
required convenience init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    let petID = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "id") as! Int
    let petName = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "name") as! String
    let petGroup = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "groupID") as! Int
    let breedID = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "breedID") as! Int
    let weight = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "weight") as! Int
    let chipNum = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "chipNum") as! Int
    let image = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "image") as! String
    self.init(id: petID, name: petName, groupID: petGroup, breedID: breedID, weight: weight, chipNum: chipNum, imageURL: image)
}

func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder){
    aCoder.encode(self.id, forKey: "id")
    aCoder.encode(self.name, forKey: "name")
    aCoder.encode(self.groupID, forKey: "groupID")
    aCoder.encode(self.breedID, forKey: "breedID")
    aCoder.encode(self.weight, forKey: "weight")
    aCoder.encode(self.chipNum, forKey: "chipNum")
    aCoder.encode(self.imageURL, forKey: "image")
//        aCoder.encode(self.petImage, forKey: "petImage")
    }
}
```

I've tried few different things so far. I even tried to move the code starting from dispatch.enter() to dispatch.wait() in another function, call that function from init, then call super.init() above the newly created function call. While this compiles and "runs" the app, it won't get past the launch screen and is stuck in the launch screen forever.

I see that all the variables that are being used are properly initialized so I'm not sure why I'm getting this error "'self' captured by a closure before all members were initialized"

I must keep this asynchronous call to the server to fetch the image. While it works when it's not asynchronous, it is a very dangerous practice and might crash when the connection to the server times out.

Any insights or feedback is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: offtopic but why do you first make the properties optional? When you initialise them there are not-optionals. What is the point of that?

Comment: @J. Doe: Just a habit of mine declaring all the variables as optional.